# Как происходит копирование массивов в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
var x = new Array(0);
var y = new  Array(0);
x = y;
y.push(3);
console.log(x);
```

x = [3];
разве так должно быть?

Comment: да ты присвоил обоим массивам одинаковые ссылки x = y;

Answer (score 2):

Да, потому-что массив в js это объект, а объекты [присваиваются по ссылке](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-reference), а не по значению. Скопировать значение объекта можно с помощью [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
var x =[1];
var y =[2];
Object.assign(x,y);
y.push(3);
console.log(x,y);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = y;
```

Теперь массив записанный в `х` был уничтожен сборщиком мусора, т.к. на него не осталось ссылки. Остались две переменные `x` и `y` которые указывают на один и тот же массив, т.к. в JS массивы передаются по ссылке. Далее думаю понятно.